# Possible to Stringize a Polars Expression?

Tags: sql, string, expression, python-polars

Is it possible to stringize a Polars expression and vice-versa?

For example, convert `df.filter(pl.col('a')<10)` to a string of `"df.filter(pl.col('a')<10)"`.

Is roundtripping possible e.g. `eval("df.filter(pl.col('a')<10)")` for user input or tool automation?

I know this can be done with a SQL expression but I'm interested in native. I want to show the specified filter in the title of plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Expressions

```py
>>> expr = pl.col("foo") > 2
>>> print(str(expr))
[(col("foo")) > (2i32)]
```

### LazyFrames

```py
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({
...     "foo": [1, 2, 3]
... })
>>> json_state = df.lazy().filter(expr).write_json()
>>> query_plan = pl.LazyFrame.from_json(json_state)
>>> query_plan.collect()
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────┐
│ foo │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 3   │
└─────┘
```

Comment: Stringize question is answered. However, I wasn't clear that I was interested in round-tripping e.g. `eval("[(col("foo")) > (2i32)]")`. Is there something similar to eval()?

Comment: `[(col("foo")) > (2i32)]` should be displayed as `[col("foo") > 2i32]`. The expression display logic should only add parenthesis if an inner expression contains a priority dependent operator. e.g. > but not .gt(2i32).

Comment: For round tripping you can dump to json. Regarding the string representation. An extra bracket is not wrong, it can only be elided, you are invited to make a PR to do so.

Comment: I opened an enhancement issue. Low priority of course. But if someone refactors, it could be considered.

Comment: The more I learn polars the more I love it. This way of encoding filters is really a strong feature.

Comment: Is there a rust version of the from_json function? For the life of me I'm not able to find one...